# Check if input is in range. HASURA - GRAPHQL

Tags: graphql, hasura

I would like to check if a number is in a specific range dynamically. For example i have a table like:

| id | value | age_range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 3-7 |
| 2 | b | 7-10 |
| 3 | c | 3-7 |
| 4 | d | 0-3 |

if the age of the user is 5, i would like to retrieve all rows where age_range is 3-7 without writing the range in the where clause query. For example something like:

```
table (where: { 5 in age_range })...
```

Comment: I would create view with calculated field and register it hasura. Actually it looks like 'hasura way' - when graphql is not enough, solve it on postgresql level.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `age_from` and an `age_to` column if possible.

```
query MyQuery($int: Int!) {
  table(where: {_and: [{age_to: {_gte: $int}}, {age_from: {_lte: $int}}]}) {
    #Fields....
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be achiieved easier with VIEW without touching source table

Comment: True. But if the schema is still flexible, I would use a natively supported type.